# Image is not drawing on canvas (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am trying to draw an image on a canvas, in **HTML5**. For some reason, the image simply isn't drawn onto the `canvas`, and there are no errors in the console. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img id="image" src="Images/player.png"></img>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="750"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var image = document.getElementById("image");

            context.fillStyle = "lightblue";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: Is the image shown on the page at all? It should, because you've added an img tag. If it isn't, then the path to the player.png is most likely incorrect. Are you sure the Images directory is spelled with a capital I? Is the Images directory below the directory where your HTML file is located?

Comment: It is appearing next to the canvas, but it is not being drawn onto the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to the `img` tag called `load`. Then in the callback you can call `drawImage` with the provided `img` element.

You can do something like this - I have added one stackoverflow image for representation:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const image = document.getElementById("image");

context.fillStyle = "lightblue";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);

image.addEventListener('load', e => context.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow-oct-19/images2/header-podcast.svg" height="100px"></img>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="750"></canvas>
```

From the documentation: [Drawing an image to the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using this in a space invaders game, so I am constantly drawing the image onto the canvas using the setInterval() function. How would I constantly draw an image onto the canvas, within this interval?

Comment: That sounds a different situation. Do you have a code snippet for that?

Comment: @PrimeCubed Just await the image load once, before the game starts. Then, you can draw it anytime: once the image is loaded, it won't be unloaded from the `<img>`.